# Sub setting data based on an ID's factor in R

Tags: r, data-manipulation

So im trying to think about how to manipulate data as such. Lets say I had a data frame like the one below.

```
ID  Factor More_data_columns
1     1         ....
2     1         ....
3     1         ....
4     2         ....
5     3         ....
```

Now is there a way to select Id 2 and then based on Id 2's factor subset the rest of the data into a new data frame?

```
Id 2: 

Factor More_data_columns
1         ....
1         ....
1         ....
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
a <- data.frame(ID = 1:5, Factor = c(1,1,1,2,3), More_Data = 6:10)

ID <- 1

a[a$Factor == a$Factor[a$ID == ID],]
#ID Factor More_Data
#1  1      1         6
#2  2      1         7
#3  3      1         8
```

Comment: Original post was adjusted to clarify the ID = 2.  But the code still works for whatever you put into the `ID` variable.

Comment: could of been 1 or 2 was just making things more correct. But it works great in my shiny app.